# Merge Tags [amazon-sagemaker] [sagemaker] into [aws-sagemaker]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The following three are duplicates, can be merged to [aws-sagemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sagemaker)

- [amazon-sagemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-sagemaker)
- [sagemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sagemaker)
- [aws-sagemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sagemaker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[amazon-sagemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-sagemaker) had more questions than both [aws-sagemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sagemaker) (48) and [sagemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sagemaker) (57) put together, therefore it was clear that the amazon sagemaker tag was being used primarily in order to identify the tech. (We cannot create synonyms in a reverse direction, where the smaller tag is the master, unless, we retag them completely)

Also, the [amazon-sagemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-sagemaker) already had a wiki setup, whereas the others did not have. Therefore, I made [amazon-sagemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-sagemaker) the master tag. [sagemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sagemaker) and [aws-sagemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sagemaker) are its synonyms now.